# VBA - How to Set Cursor in a Specific Position in a Textbox?

Tags: vba, textbox, text-cursor

The title mostly explains what I need. I have a textbox that I continuously examine for data validity using the `_keypress` procedure. If the user enters `(` then I auto-fill it for them by typing the closing parenthesis `)`. The result is `()` and the cursor is at the end of the textbox. 
My question is, how can I push the cursor back one step to put it between the two parenthesis? Thanks,

Edit: Test scenario:

```
Private Sub txtInput_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    If KeyAscii = Asc("(") Then
        txtInput.value = txtInput.value & "()"
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this makes it more clear,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `SelStart` property of the `TextBox` object:

```
Me.TextBox1.Value = "()"
Me.TextBox1.SelStart = 1
```

Note: `SelStart=1` means the cursor will be after the first element, i.e. "`(`". You should hence play with your string to understand what your desired value of `SelStart` property should be.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to return the position number where the cursor is?

Comment: You will need to make a call to Windows API check https://support.microsoft.com/kb/152969/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Do I need that to return the position of the cursor in a **textbox**?

Comment: @Grendizer I guess it's the same property, SelStart. If you write "SelStart = 2" you're **setting** its value, but if you write pos = SelStart you should be **getting** its value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **SelStart** property with **Len** function

```
Me.txtInput.SelStart = Len(Me.txtInput.Value)-1
```

Using this method now you can be sure that it will always set the typing cursor between your parenthesis