# Set focus on textbox after performing print command

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me case below:
When I write code for print command by vba then it run OK.

But after run print command then cursor don't focus on textbox.

what do I must use command to cursor focus on textbox?
Thank you so much.

```
If TextBox1.Text = "PRINT" Then
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    TextBox1.Value = ""
    Call CData
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus
End If
```

Because I am writing macro for scan barcode on textbox, so I need to automatic process after perform print, it can continue receive scan barcode on textbox, no must click on textbox before scan barcode.

Comment: Have you tried just `TextBox1.SetFocus` ? or `Me.TextBox1.SetFocus` ?

Comment: I already inserted as your idea, but cursor still don't focus on Textbox1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - How to Set Cursor in a Specific Position in a Textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399480/vba-how-to-set-cursor-in-a-specific-position-in-a-textbox)

Comment: @Luuklag: When I using that code then textbox1 only display "()" and I still can not continue scan barcode. I want to after run print command then I can continue scan barcode but no need click on that textbox.

Comment: @LuongTieumuoi Dont take `"()"` as string, but use your own values.

Comment: @Luuklag: my value will change because I am writing code for san barcode, so I don't know the next is which value? I only want cursor focus on textbox to I can continue scan.

Comment: How about ‘Me.textBox1.Enabled = False’ and then ‘Me.TextBox1.Enabled = True’ then set the focus-

Answer (score 0):

1. Check first if there is any error message and where your code is located (module, userform, worksheet or workbook code).
2. Are you sure that your `If TextBox1.Text = "PRINT"` condition is executed? Check this by inserting a `beep` command, some `Debug.Print` info for the immediate window or a `Stop` command allowing you to check code continuation manually by pressing `F8`.
3. You could try `Windows(ThisWorkbook.name).Activate` instead of only `ThisWorkbook.Activate`, especially if you are using more than one workbook and do some selection or activating.
4. If the TextBox situated on a page of a MultiPage control, you should activate this page first: e.g. `Multipage1.Value = 0` (...) and then set focus via `TextBox1.SetFocus`.
5. Don't reference :-) `UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus`, but use `Me.TextBox1.SetFocus`or `TextBox1.SetFocus` :-) if this is code withIN your UserForm module.
6. You could also perform a Click() event on your TextBox, though that isn't best programming style: `TextBox1_Click`

Comment: I tried make it as your commend, but cursor still not focus on textbox.

Comment: Which is the exact procedure where this part of code is located? Is this a userform control event like xy_Click() or xy_Change in your UserForm or is it a Worksheet procedure with a TextBox placed in a sheet?

Comment: (2) Please edit your post and add also your code that prints out as well as any event code referring to TextBox1, e.g. TextBox1_Change, TextBox1_Click, TextBox1_Exit ...